# Monitoring the performance of Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, gridgain

> I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0
>   GridGain web console is used to monitor the live performance of Ignite.
>   Is there possible to Monitor the history records? 
>   Example, I need view the performance of last week, is there possible by GridGain web console?
>
> Initially when i downloaded that the size is 77MB, but now size is 256MB. So i got doubt as whether it will store the data anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain Control Center, the next monitoring tool from GridGain that will substitute Web Console, supports tracing capabilities and more advanced monitoring dashboards that can work with historical data: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/overview

Comment: History means .. can i check last month records?

Comment: History means .. can i check last month records?

Comment: The hosted version of Control Center should keep the history of the last several days. Once tool becomes available for an installation in your environment (beginning of July 2020), you will be able to keep the history of as long as needed.